# Updating database structure to nested sets (baum) - family tree

Tags: php, laravel, nested

So I originally was using `mother_id` and `father_id` on the `persons` table
Now due to problems where you can't load all the mothers and fathers recursively with just one query I wanted to change this since it's getting slow now that family trees become "deeper".

After some googling I quickly saw that nested sets (using: "gazsp/baum") is a recommended way of handle this.

From what I could tell this would be the proper(?) setup to use:

```
     ___________________________________________________________________
|  Root - Person that is no parent of anyone                        |
|    ____________________________    ____________________________   |
|   |  First Child - Father     |   |  Second Child - Mother    |   |
|   |   __________   _________  |   |   __________   _________  |   |
|   |  |  Father |  | Mother |  |   |  |  Father  |  | Mother|  |   |
1   2  3_________4  5________6  7   8  9_________10 11_______12 13  14
|   |___________________________|   |___________________________|   |
|___________________________________________________________________|
```

Now I'm having trouble translating my `mother_id` and `father_id` relationships to the new version. What I did was first loop over all the person and make them roots by default. I seemed to get some problems otherwise which I assume was due to fields being NULL.

Now I followed that up with the following code which I expected to properly translate my old relations to nested sets.

```
$allPersons = \App\Person::all();

foreach($allPersons as $person)
{
    if($person->father_id != 0)
    {
        $allPersons->find($person->father_id)->makeChildOf($person);
        $person->father_id = 0;
    }

    if($person->mother_id != 0)
    {
        $allPersons->find($person->mother_id)->makeChildOf($person);
        $person->mother_id = 0;
    }
    $person->save();
}
```

I get the following error multiple times while I couldn't find any problems with the structure. I couldn't find any loops or errors that may cause this.

```
A node cannot be moved to a descendant of itself (inside moved tree).
```

I also tried to add the following before making the father / mother a "child"(The naming does confuse me often due to the context I'm using it in). This doesn't seem to catch out the error, while looking at the error message I suppose it should.

```
$mother = $allPersons->find($person->mother_id);
if($mother->isSelfOrDescendantOf($person)) dd('Already descendant');
$mother->makeChildOf($person);
```

**I've been working on this quite a while now and I'm not making any progress anymore. Am I using nested sets wrong? Is my "translate" script incorrect or do you have a better solution then nested sets please tell me.**

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling to build the similar database structure for a full day so sharing my approach to help others in the same situation.
As far as I know, nested sets are not proper for the genealogical graph in the relational databases although it looks perfect for the tree structure like folders.
The best way for your scenario is the path enumeration mechanism which is explained in here:
https://www.waitingforcode.com/mysql/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-path-enumeration/read

Animal table (Person table in your case) will look like this (You could define other info like gender, name, etc or have another relation table like AnimalTree but let's focus on the mandatory fields).

| id | generation(depth) | father_id | mother_id | path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL | NULL | '1.' |
| 2 | 1 | NULL | NULL | '2.' |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | '1.2.3.' |
| 4 | 3 | 3 | 2 | '1.2.3.4.' |

...

Note that I don't append the mother's id to the child's path for the grandchild's path because it's redundant.

`generation = Math.max(father.generation, mother.generation) + 1;`

To retrieve a full tree for grandfather:
`SELECT * FROM Animal WHERE path LIKE '1.%';`

To retrieve the single path for a grandchild:
`SELECT * FROM Animal WHERE id in (1, 2, 3, 4);`

Hope it helps.